# IdNotify : How to pass parameteres to function

Tags: indy, lazarus

I have code typhoon with lazarus installed after a long strugle I have managed to include the unit IdSync to my project.

How can I pass parameteres to a function that I want to execute in the main thread from TIdNotify ?

Comment: You don't mention what error your get.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort I don't get any error friend.I was just asking what is the proper way to pass parameters to a function using TidNotify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the TIdNotify.DoNotify() method, then you can pass whatever parameters you want, eg:

```
type
  TMyNotify = class(TIdNotify)
  protected
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  end;

procedure TMyNotify.DoNotify;
begin
  SomeFunction(parameters);
end;
```

.

```
begin
  ...
  TMyNotify.Create.Notify;
  ...
end;
```

Presumably, you want the calling thread to specify the parameter values, so just make them members of the class, eg:

```
type
  TMyNotify = class(TIdNotify)
  protected
    Param1: SomeType;
    Param2: SomeType;
    Param3: SomeType;
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  end;

procedure TMyNotify.DoNotify;
begin
  SomeFunction(Param1, Param2, Param2);
end;
```

.

```
begin
  ...
  with TMyNotify.Create do
  begin
    Param1 := ...;
    Param2 := ...;
    Param3 := ...
    Notify;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your support.Any idea why IdSync is not compiling in lazarus by default ?

Comment: No, because you did not explain what kind of problem you are having with it.

Comment: http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php/forum/general-discussions/2346-idsync-not-found#2849

Comment: Either Lazarus is not configured correctly to find the IdSync unit, or the pl_indycomp package was simply compiled without the IdSync unit in it. I'm not a Lazarus user, so I cannot help with that.