# Using anonymous function with TIdSync

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12184988/1894275) I can sync my functions with main thread. And thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13618465/1894275) I can pass parameters too. But the problem is I must declare multiple class for various procedures because parameters are different (count or type).

Q: Can I use anonymous function with TIdSync (or any other solution) so there is no need to define multiple class for various procedures?

Answer (score 2):

`TIdSync` and `TIdNotify` do not support anonymous procedures/functions, as it would be redundant because `TThread.Synchronize()` and `TThread.Queue()` themselves support anonymous procedures (and they have static overloads that do not require a `TThread` object, when you are working with non-RTL threads).  For example:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  ...
  Synchronize(
    procedure
    begin
      SomeFunction(Param1, Param2, Param2);
    end
  ...
  Queue(
    procedure
    begin
      SomeFunction(Param1, Param2, Param2);
    end
  );
  ...
end;
```

```
// CreateThread() procedure
function MyThreadProc(pv: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
begin
  ...
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      SomeFunction(Param1, Param2, Param2);
    end
  );
  ...
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      SomeFunction(Param1, Param2, Param2);
    end
  );
  ...
  Result := 0;
end;
```

`TIdSync` is just a wrapper for `TThread.Synchronize()` and `TIdNotify` is just a wrapper for `TThread.Queue()`.  They were introduced in a time when all `TThread` had available was the non-static non-anonymous `Synchronize()` method.  With the introduction of static methods and anonymous procedures into `TThread`, it now does just about everything that `TIdSync` and `TIdNotify` were designed to do, making them less relevant (but they still work, of course).

Comment: Thanks. Good information. Sorry for late reply. But `SomeFunction` do not executed as expected. Seems some packets not received by `SomeFunction` (or `SomeFunction` executed sometimes). Also `SomeFunction` worked great with TIdSync approach. Also it worked with Synchronize. I searched a bit and in this [link](http://delphi.about.com/b/2011/04/14/synchronizing-threads-and-gui-in-delphi-application.htm) in the last comment there is notice about `TThread.Queue` by Michael Schnell, but I don't understand how to take care. Thanks.

Comment: `TIdSync` simply calls `TThread.Synchronize()`. `TThread.Queue()` uses the same queue that `TThread.Synchronize()` uses. They both put a request in a global queue for the main thread to process at its leisure. So if `SomeFunction()` is not being called then the main thread is not processing sync requests, and that would affect `TThread`, `TIdSync`, and `TIdNotify` equally.